# Coded UI Test : 'Unable to copy to clipboard' to generate actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I was trying to records actions in my Windows 10 PC, but I found that apps on Windows 10 are based on UWP.

I found it in this question: Coded UI Test project template for Windows Store apps? (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42ce7c49-ffce-43b3-8902-12d10d1db3fe/coded-ui-test-project-template-for-windows-store-apps?forum=vsunittest)

So I tried to do it as mention here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/test-windows-store-8-1-apps-with-coded-ui-tests?view=vs-2015
"Using the cross-hair tool in the Coded UI Test Builder to select the app tile, right-click AutomationId and choose Copy Value to Clipboard. The value in the clipboard will be used later for writing action to launch the app for testing."

But after click Copy Value to Clipboard, I got an error 'Unable to copy to clipboard

How can I fix this issue?

I already did the following:
* Right click: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CodedUITestBuilder.exe"
* Check: "Properties\Compatability\Change settings for all users\Run the program in compatability mode for:"
* Select: Windows 7
* Check: "Properties\Compatability\Change settings for all users\Run this program as an administrator"

Current result: I'm getting an error: Unable to copy to clipboard when click 'Copy Value to Clipboard'

Expected Result: Visual Studio allows to copy and generate code

Comment: If you didn't already, try running Visual Studio as administrator.
To rule out a corrupted Visual Studio installation, you could try a repair of the installation. Also make sure you installed all the components needed.
As a workaround you could write down the automation ID, but that's not really a solution.

Comment: I already did it, even also run as administrator CodedUITestBuilder.exe, but I have same error. Additionally, I repaired VS having same result, the last try was uninstall and reinstall but also I have same error.

Comment: You could always try and use another inspection tool. Take a look at [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/inspect-objects). If it's available, you should be able to get that automationID. Just select the value by double clicking it and use ctrl+c to copy the value to clipboard. If it works, that would mean your problem is probably with Visual Studio and not with the control you try to copy its AutomationID from. If it works for you and you are happy with this solution, I'll write it as an answer.